# How to structure Mulesoft-SqlServer error handling

Tags: sql-server, mulesoft

I have a  large number of stored procedures that roughly follow this pattern

```
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT THING FROM ATABLE;
  EXEC ASTOREDPROC;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  EXEC LOGERROR;
  THROW;
END CATCH;
```

I am told this is a problem for our Mule team;  apparently, if the SELECT occurs, but the stored procedure fails, Mule will detect the resultset but not the exception.

The proposed solution is to rewrite the code so that result sets are only yielded after exceptions have been ruled out. (by inserting to temp tables, perhaps)

In principle I object to tailoring stored procedures to accommodate their consumers.

In practice this will probably work but it is clearly flawed; it assumes we can write code that would NEVER fail - outside the try..catch.

What available approaches are there to solve this issue?

Most importantly - how does Mule solve this problem?

Comment: This isn't just a mulesoft issue. Consumers must consume all results and messages returned by SQL Server in order for the exception to be raised. More info [here](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).

Comment: @DanGuzman - excellent article, thanks.  Perhaps I should just simply ask how to ensure Mulesoft consumes all results; our c# code already does this.

Comment: I agree another question about mulesoft is in order. Even if the product doesn't support returning multiple result sets, it should at least consume them to ensure errors are raised. One can argue it's a bug in the product if not. Glad to hear you C# apps do that as it's not commonly done.